# How to write a test to verify using Selenium Web Browser Automation

Tags: python, selenium

I'm very new to Selenium Web Browser Automation. 
I'm trying to write a test to verify a that the menu item for About actually goes to the About page in "http://www.seleniumhq.org/"
Do you guys have an idea of how to achieve this by using Selenium Web Browser Automation Python??
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Locate the `About` link by *link text*, click it and check what the value of `driver.title` is:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/")

driver.find_element_by_link_text("About").click()

assert driver.title == "About Selenium"

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, determine what(element,text,link,img etc) in the loaded about page you will use to validate that you are in correct(about) page. 
Then construct your code like this-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org")
driver.find_element_by_id("menu_about").click()
#Assertion 1
assert 'About' in driver.title
#Assertion 2
assert 'about' in driver.current_url
#console log
print('Title of the current page is: ' + driver.title)
print('Current URL is : ' + driver.current_url)
driver.close()
```